# objective-c broken pointer with callback woes

Tags: objective-c, ios, pointers, memory-management

I'm having trouble with a broken pointer that's pointing to garbage after an object has been released. **objectA** is the delegate for a callback from another object, **objectB**.
**objectA** is being allocated and released quite often (in my application its a menu UI object). Every time **objectA** is being initialised it initialises **objectB** and begins an asynchronous operation and then calls back to **objectA** via the id delegate property.
How can I stop my pointer: id delegate from breaking ?

```
ObjA.m
-(void)dealloc{
     [super dealloc];
} 

+(id)init{
     ObjA *objectA = [[ObjA alloc]init];
     return objectA;
}
-(id)init{
     if (self == [super init]){
         ObjB *objectB = [ObjB initialiseWithDelegate:self];

     }
     return self;
}    
-(void)callback:(id)arg{
     //This callback is called from an asynchronous routine from  objectB 

}
-(void)terminate{
  //This is called when I want to remove/release objectA
  //Other logical termination code here
  [self release];
}


ObjB.m
@synthesize delegate;

+(id)initialiseWithDelegate:(id)delegate{
     ObjB *objectB = [[ObjB alloc]init];
     [objectB setDelegate:delegate];
     return objectB;
}
-(id)init{
     if (self == [super init]){
         [self beginAsynchronousOperation];

     }
     return self;
}
-(void)beginAsynchronousOperation{
     //Do asynchronous stuff here
}
-(void)finishedAsynchronousOperation{
     //Called when asynch operation is complete

     if (self.delegate) [self.delegate callback:someargument]; //EXC error. Pointer broke

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer here is that you `nil` out objectB's `delegate` property when you dealloc objectA. Because delegates are assigned, and not retained (explicitly to prevent retain cycles), as you have seen, the delegate reference can be left hanging when the "owning" object goes away. Typically objectA will be holding a retained reference to objectB, and during objectA's `dealloc`, it will first set objectB's `delegate` to `nil`, and then `release` objectB. This will prevent the crash. Of course this assumes (as is typical) that you don't *need* to do anything with that async completion. It also assumes that objectB can safely be released by objectA when it is in the middle of an async operation. This is usually true of (say) animations, but if you're building your own tasks, you might need to be careful of the lifetimes here.

Some notes on this code snippet that might be helpful:

1. Your objectA isn't actually holding a reference to objectB once it's created. This means you can't nil out the delegate. You should keep the reference to objectB when it's created so you can do this.
2. You are leaking objectB. ObjectA creates it (alloc, init), but then drops the reference, so even when it's done, no one seems to be responsible for releasing it. Again, holding it so you can release it will fix this too.
3. Your `-terminate` on objectA is an anti-pattern-- an object should never (with only one exception: a failure inside `init`) be calling `-release` on `self`. An object should be released by its owner, which is whoever originally created *it*.
4. Your pattern of `if (self == [super init])` is normally written with one equals sign, meaning that you're both assigning `self` to the result as well as checking it for `nil`. This is a Cocoa historical oddity, and probably makes no difference here, but worth pointing out.

Comment: Excellent answer! Do you know any decent reads on "anti-patterns" or patterns? I never thought that [self release] could be detrimental.
I'll need to incorporate a means to hold the references as you suggested, alternatively I could stop the asynchronous operation completely in so that it doesn't callback.
Thanks for the assistance!. Oliver

Comment: @Oliver: You can simply hold the reference as an instance variable or property on objectA. Glad to help. There's a book called "Cocoa Design Patterns" which I think is a little overwrought, but might be helpful for you to skim through. Also if you're new (or really, even if you're not) I like Aaron Hillegass's books for their clarity and pragmatism.